# How to map mapzen boundary extracts with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I downloaded .geojson files from mapzen metro extracts that is supposed to show the outline of a neighborhood. However, when I run the javascript code that I have written, nothing is appended to the "g" element and thus nothing shows up.

Here is the code that I have now:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 760)
    .attr("height", 700);

  d3.json("wayland.geojson", function (data){
      console.log(data);

      var nb = canvas.append("g")
                      .attr("class","nb");

      var group = nb.selectAll("path")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath());
  });
```

The geojson file in question is valid and is a Feature, so I was just wondering how to map such a file correctly.

```
Object {id: 85854865, type: "Feature", properties: Object, bbox: Array(4), geometry: Object}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a projection for `d3.geoPath()`, if you do not specify a projection, d3 defaults to a null projection. A null projection takes geographic coordinates and simply turns them into svg/canvas coordinates with no transformation at all. Thus, if you have lat/long pairs in your geojson, only points from `0,0` to `90,180` will show, so anything in the western or sourthern hemispheres will not work. However, no errors will be produced because the null projection and the geoPath are working as expected.

*Note, d3 projections take coordinates that use the WGS84 datum, that is latitude longitude pairs using the WGS84 ellipsoid, generally most lat long pairs will use this datum (GPS, google earth, etc). If your data is projected already, then d3 geoProjections are not what you need, you'll need geoTransforms*

---

Instead of using a null projection, try to define a projection. There are a few ways to do this, one is the fitExtent method (as you are using d3 v4):

```
    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .fitExtent([[40,40],[width-40,height-40]], geojson);
```

This will take a set of geojson features (not topojson) and place a 40 pixel buffer around the features using a mercator map projection.

---

Another option is to look at your bbox coordinates and find the center of your area of interest (or use Google Earth etc) and set the projection manually:

```
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .center([0,y])
    .rotate([-x,0])
    .scale(10000);
```

Scale values increase as you zoom in, so starting with a low value is always useful to ensure you are looking in the right area. Neighborhood level details will be very zoomed in though.

---

Projection type won't be too important at a neighborhood level, but setting the parameters correctly will be.

Lastly, you'll need to make sure your geoPath uses your projection:

```
geoPath.projection(projection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried adding `var projection = d3.geoMercator()
                .fitExtent([[40,40],["width"-40,"height"-40]]);

          var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);` to the original code, but still nothing showed up. What would be the reason behind this? Thank you!

Comment: You need to specify what geojson feature (feature set) you are fitting the extent too - the geojson variable in the answer's code that I don't see in your code block. And width and height aren't strings but values for the height and width of your map canvas/svg.

Comment: Hmmm... sorry I'm not sure I understood the "feature" part. Would you mind taking a look at the .geojson file [link](https://pastebin.com/BU14tT6U)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: your code block here: `d3.geoMercator().fitXtent([[40,40],[width-40,height-40]])` is not fitting any geographic feature, if you see the code block above, it has a variable for your geojson, which in your case is `data`, you need to specify this because you need to state what you want the projection to center on. So you'd probably just use `.fitExtent([[40,40],[width-40,height-40]], data);`, your data variable for this use has to be a geojson feature or geojson feature collection.